# Combinatorial optimization for puzzle solving

Tags: optimization, knapsack-problem

My problem is explained in the following image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6mZt.png

I have a finite (but rather large) amount of such pieces that need to be stacked in a way so that the REMAINING area is the smallest possible. The pieces are locked in the horizontal axis (time) and have fixed height. They can only be stacked.

The remaining area is defined by the maximum point of the stack that depends on which pieces have been selected. The best combination in the example image would be the [1 1 0]. (The trivial [0 0 0] case will not be allowed by other constraints)

My only variables are binaries (Yes or No) for each piece. The objective is a little more complicated than what I am describing, but my greatest problem right now is how to formulate the expression

```
Max{Stacked_Pieces} - Stacked_Pieces_Profile
```

in the objective function. The result of this expression is a vector of course (timeseries) but it will be further reduced to a number through other manipulations.

Essentially my problem is how to write

```
Max{A} - A, where A = 1xN vector
```

In a way compatible with a linear (or even quadratic) objective. Or am I dealing with a non-linear problem?

*EDIT: The problem is like a Knapsack problem the main difference being that there is no knapsack to fill up. i.e. the size of the knapsack varies according to the selected pieces and is always equal to the top of the stacked profile*

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Isn't this a knapsack problem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: yes it is, but the size of my knapsack changes with the change of combinations. The maximum is not fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you can basically try to solve it as a normal knapsack problem in multiple iterations, finding the minimal.

Now, finding the height of the knapsack is a problem, which means you need multiple iterations. Because you need to solve the knapsack problem to see if a certain height will work, you need multiple iterations.

Note that you do know an upper and a lower bound for the height. I'm not sure if rotation is applicable, but you can fill in the gaps here:

- Min = max(max height of smallest piece, total size / width)
- Max = sum(height of all pieces).

Basically solving it means finding the smallest height [Min <= x <= Max] that fits all pieces. The easiest way to do that is by using a 'for' loop, but you can do it better:

1. Try min, max, half
2. if half fits -> max = half; iterate (goto 1)
3. if half doesn't fit -> min = half; iterate (goto 1)

As for solving the knapsack problem, for each iteration, I'd check if all pieces can still be fitted. Use bit-masks and AND/OR/XOR operations if you can to speed things up.

Basically you can do it like this:

- Grab bit 'x'. Fill with next block
- Check if this leads to a possible solution
- Find next bit that can be filled

Note that you might want to use intrinsics in C++ to speed this up. Modern CPU's are quite good with this.

As for code: I've made some code that solves the bedlam cube in the past; I'm pretty sure that if you google for that, you'll find some fast solvers.

Good luck!

Comment: This approach seems promising. I have to re-check it with a large set of data as well, but in smaller examples, I get the same results with the full enumeration method. Thanx a lot!